# How to make a Bobble error for required field in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have used the below the code for make required field but I need to show like below image

[image]

Please check following link to view my code 
My Code :  [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mikiqex/US4sr/8/)

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="formID">
    Your name: <input id="yourname" required /><span id="yournameMsg" style="margin-left:6px;color:darkred;"></span>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**Note : I have used Safari browser.**

Thanks

Comment: You should wether use a third-party tool, learn how to code it yourself or hire someone who can. So is not a "please code this for me" site.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/US4sr/18/ error shows in same place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be closer to what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/mikiqex/US4sr/15/

Please note that the whole tip (arrow, triangle) has to be in a solid color, so it can't be bordered like in your picture above.

It's customized CSS from http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/demo/

```
.triangle-isosceles:after {
    border-color: #ddd transparent;
    border-width: 0 10px 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    bottom: auto;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    left: 30px;
    top: -10px;
}
.triangle-isosceles {
    background: #ddd;
    box-shadow:0 1px 3px #888;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    color: #000000;
    margin-top:6px;
    margin-left:130px;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    position: absolute;
    width:160px;
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: You are really genius.. kindly share your skype.. please

Comment: Sorry, I use Skype for business matters only. Besides, I can't teach you how to code as it would take time I don't have.

Comment: Ok NP. We will communicate through here.. 2 more question only 1. how to hide that error msg when got the focus of that textfield. 2. Is there any possible to make that pop up like my image.. see my question immage(with exclamatory symbol)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mikiqex/US4sr/22/ I used a pic I googled, it was just about edit CSS background for the bubble. Feel free to play with the fiddle, to understand what I did there (I added some comments).

Comment: Really amazing ; I have put that name as validation() for that javascript and i have called in another function. So, how to achieve this just comment: <script> function validate(){you code} function mycode{ validation(); nextmethod()// it will execute only when full all the record}</script>

Comment: I need to Skip. next method if error validation(); method2();// I want to skip method2. if any error showed in textfield.

Comment: You can return true/false from the function validate. True if everything is OK, false if error occured: function validate() { var hasErrors = false; ..do stuff.. return hasError;} function mycode { if (validation()) nextmethod(); }. Somewhere in "..do stuff.." you set hasErrors = true; if error occured.

Comment: see what I am missing here http://jsfiddle.net/US4sr/23/ I have tried last 4 hours :(

Comment: To be brutally honest, you're missing basics of JavaScript and connection between JS and HTML. From the Fiddle I have no clear idea what are you trying to achieve, but if you're trying what I think, it won't work this way (in fact, the whole solution is wrong for this kind of purpose). As this is again beyond the question, my work here is done and I'm out. Read some books, try some basic examples, find a lecture. I don't do tutorage or somebody else's job. Sorry.

Comment: I want to get the result of "r" value from other function so how to do. I am the expert of salesforce but dont know about javascript. I am develop big application. so pls help.

Comment: test() is executed automatically when page loads, but "r" changes it's value into "change" when page is submitted by user. There's no good way how to connect those two worlds. You can't build big app using Stack Overflow. Learn it first (that's hundreds of hours) or hire somebody. My stack has overflown.

Comment: Hi. Just resolve this only after that I never ask you. How to get the value because I am trying to stop next method like this: if(r == change){call next method} else{ return false}

Comment: You have to do it at the same time. I tried to modify your Fiddle to keep it as much as original, but to work: http://jsfiddle.net/mikiqex/US4sr/24/ Function test() is now called when user tries to submit the form, before it was called when the page loaded. I saw no point of "change", so I removed it :) Instead I use return value of validation().

Answer (score 0):

Try to use jquery validate plugin and the tooltip from jquery ui or third part plugin.

Answer (score 0):

solution in jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/US4sr/9/

**To learn more:**

Use HTML5 inputs and style the bubble by CSS3,

**HTML5 Input example:**

```
<input type="number" />
```

**CSS3 options:**

```
::-webkit-validation-bubble

::-webkit-validation-bubble-arrow-clipper 

::-webkit-validation-bubble-arrow 

::-webkit-validation-bubble-message
```

**Check this article:**

http://www.broken-links.com/2011/06/16/styling-html5-form-validation-errors/

**Or use 'jQuery inline form validation':**

http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html

Comment: Genius... If we want to show left bottom means where will i change